# Help with Strings in C

Tags: c

Given the  char * variables  name1 ,  name2 , and  name3 , write a fragment of code that assigns the largest value to the variable  max (assume all three have already been declared and have been assigned values).

I've tried and came up with this:

```
    if ((strcmp(name1,name2)>0)&&(strcmp(name1,name3)>0)){
max=name1;
}
else if ((strcmp(name2,name1)>0)&&(strcmp(name2,name3)>0)){
max=name2;
}
else if((strcmp(name3,name1)>0)&&(strcmp(name3,name2)>0)){
max=name3;
}
else if(strcmp(name3,name1)==0){
max=name1,name3;
}
else if (strcmp(name2,name1)==0){
max=name2,name1;
}
else if (strcmp(name2,name3)==0){
max=name2,name3;
}
else{
max=name1,name2,name3;
}
```

However, I get this error Your code is incorrect. You are not handling the situation
               where two or more strings are equal.

Solved...

Comment: How do you get that error?  Is it from a person?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Look at your code carefully and consider what it does if all 3 strings are equal. (Among other cases)

Comment: If all three strings are equal then there would be no largest value... What am I missing...

Comment: What is the largest value in the set (10, 10, 10)?  The smallest value?

Comment: Sounds like homework, I'll update the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`strcmp` returns 0 when your strings are equal</strike>

I'll leave it for you to figure out why you aren't handling it.

**Edit:**

Bob and Alice are 10 years old.
What is the max age?

Hint: it's not undefined.... it's 10.

Comment: 100% agree with that statement!

Comment: Yeah and it returns a positive value if x>y in terms of strcmp(x,y).

Comment: Wow, I finally got it... I like how you guys make me solve the answer myself without providing code.

Answer (score 1):

**Watch out:** `strcmp` does *not* do numeric comparison!

That is

```
strcmp("10","2")
```

returns a negative value, indicating that `"2"` is bigger than `"10"` which is almost certainly *not* what you want.

You probably want to convert the strings to numbers of some kind before comparing. Consider using `sprintf` or `atoi` or `atof` or `strtod`.